# Faster computation of hash value for a large vector of doubles

Tags: c++, boost, hash

I need to calculate the hash value for a large vector. Currently I do it with a for-loop and boost::hash_combine as shown below, but it is too slow - it takes close to 10ms for a 500000 size vector, but ideally I'd like to bring it down to 1ms or lesser. Is there a way to compute the hash faster(in one-shot perhaps?) for contents in a contiguous block of memory like a vector instead of having to parse through the entire vector with a for-loop?

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional> // bind
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main () 
{

    vector<double> myContainer(500000, 0.0);
    
    uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0.0,1.0);
    mt19937 re(std::random_device{}());
    auto generator = std::bind(unif, std::ref(re));
    generate(begin(myContainer), end(myContainer), generator);
    
    cout << "myContainer[0] = " << myContainer[0] << ", myContainer[L-1] = " << myContainer[myContainer.size()-1] << std::endl;
    
    size_t      hashValBoost(0);     // type supported by boost::hash_combine
    uint64_t startTime_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    for(size_t i=0; i<myContainer.size(); ++i)
    {
        boost::hash_combine(hashValBoost, myContainer[i]);
    }
    uint64_t endTime_us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();

    cout << "ContainerSize = " << myContainer.size() <<"; Container hash = " << hashValBoost << ", TimeToComputeHash(ms) = " << (endTime_us - startTime_us)/1000.0 << "ms" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I am constrained to build without turning optimizations on and with C++11 or older compiler.

Run code here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/gxVxZ8QE53DhtZde

Comment: Do you really need to hash the entire container?

Comment: If you turn optimization on (checkbox on the left) it's around 1.5ms.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, the requirement is to use the hash value as a unique identifier of the array to avoid repetition of file I/O for test time reduction.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, I observed that, but unfortunately the makefile I'm constrained to use as is, does not have -O2 compiler flag enabled. Artyer's solution gives a 10x improvement in execution time even without optimization turned on.

Comment: Optimization would likely speed up your whole program, including the code in the answer, but you're leaving all that off the table. Makes sense.

Comment: "I am constrained to build without turning optimizations on." - end of story. The question is unanswerable then

Comment: Also, "using namespace", but then ... `    uint64_t startTime_us =
        std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
            std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()
                .time_since_epoch())
            .count();` ? What about really saving on typing without sacrificing good practice: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/vccrx7P4W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your vector does not contain `NaN`s or negative zeroes, you can leverage more heavily optimized byte array hashing algorithms:

```cpp
std::size_t hash_bytes(std::span<const std::byte> sp) {
    std::string_view sv(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(sp.data()), sp.size())
    return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(sv);
    
    // Or some other byte based hashing algorithm, like
    
    // boost::hash_range is optimized for std::byte and unsigned char
    return boost::hash_range(sp.begin(), sp.end());
}

// Usage: hashVal = hash_bytes(std::as_bytes(std::span(myContainer)))
```

Boost also has `boost::hash_value(const std::vector<T>&)` or `boost::hash_range(It, It)`, which internally does the `hash_combine` loop. It's about ~4x slower, but will still work if you have negative zeroes/`NaN`s.

Comment: Can the vector directly be passed into hash_bytes() or is some conversion needed?

Comment: @Naveen The conversion is `std::as_bytes(std::span(myContainer))`. You can make the function take `const auto& r` instead and do that in the function, but I wouldn't recommend it as it's less clear that it's working with the raw bytes

Comment: Note that doing the hash on a byte-by-byte level means you'll get different hash values for the same vector on big-endian vs little-endian machines.

Comment: I like this for (a) std::as_bytes is under-used and (b) the attention to detail (negative zero, e.g.).

Comment: Combined it all in a simplified side-by-side bench: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/vccrx7P4W for good measure

Comment: @Artyer Are there any alternatives for std::span and std::byte for C++11?

Comment: @Naveen Yeah, `const unsigned char* ptr, std::size_t sz`, but it's more difficult to call (`hash_bytes(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(myContainer.data()), myContainer.size() * sizeof(*myContainer.data()))`)

Comment: @Artyer Thanks. std::string_view is only supported from C++17 onward, but initializing a std::string with the char* (not unsigned char*) and sz and then using std::hash on the string works fine, albeit a bit slower.

Comment: @Naveen `std::string` requires copying all the bytes. At that point you should use `boost::hash_range(ptr, ptr + sz)`

Comment: @Artyer This works, but it is slow compared to the other methods. It doesn't look like the optimizations in hash_range for unsigned char is taking effect here. https://wandbox.org/permlink/4sSmgxfgA1sgFjIh

Comment: @Naveen You cannot time without turning on optimizations: https://wandbox.org/permlink/WSiub9zoCjjSVG0h

Comment: @Artyer Still shows a timing that is 6x slower than when C++20 functions are used and ~2x slower than plain hash_combine on the vector. Am i missing something?